# Size difference between OSX .dmg and PC installer .exe?

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

I am using `electron-builder` (mostly) successfully. I am building a .dmg and a NSIS installer .exe. The .dmg is @ 200 mb whereas the installer .exe is @ 50mb. I've dug around in the OSX app "Contents" directory to see if something is getting included which should not be but have not found anything obvious.

Is there a valid reason for the size difference or should I keep looking for a problem on my implementation and/or usage of `electron-builder`?

My package.json file is below.

```
{
  "name": "xxxxxxxx",
  "version": "1.0.0-beta.7",
  "description": "xxxxxxxx",
  "productName": "xxxxxxxx",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "APP_DEV=true electron .",
    "package": "electron-packager .  --version=0.35.6 --overwrite  --out=release-builds",
    "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite  --platform=darwin --arch=x64  --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . --overwrite  --platform=win32 --arch=x64   --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "postinstall": "install-app-deps",
    "pack": "build --dir",
    "dist": "build -mw"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "xxxxxxxx",
    "productName": "xxxxxxxx",
    "copyright": "xxxxxxxx",
    "asar": true,
    "mac": {
      "hardenedRuntime": true,
      "entitlements": "build/entitlements.mac.plist",
      "entitlementsInherit": "build/entitlements.mac.plist",
      "gatekeeperAssess": false,
      "target": [
        "dmg"
      ],
      "icon": "build/osx.png",
      "category": "public.app-category.business",
      "compression": "store",
      "files": [
        "!release-builds/*",
        "!build/*",
        "!.vscode/*",
        "!.gitignore/*"
      ]
    },
    "dmg": {
      "sign": false,
      "background": "build/osx-bng.png",
      "icon": "build/osx.png",
      "iconTextSize": 14,
      "iconSize": 80,
      "window": {
        "x": 100,
        "y": 100,
        "width": 600,
        "height": 452
      },
      "contents": [
        {
          "x": 160,
          "y": 250
        },
        {
          "x": 430,
          "y": 250,
          "type": "link",
          "path": "/Applications"
        }
      ]
    },
    "nsis": {
      "createDesktopShortcut": "always",
      "oneClick": false,
      "perMachine": false,
      "allowElevation": true,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
      "installerIcon": "build/icon.ico",
      "uninstallerIcon": "build/icon.ico",
      "installerHeaderIcon": "build/icon.ico",
      "installerSidebar": "build/installerSidebar.bmp",
      "uninstallerSidebar": "build/uninstallerSidebar.bmp",
      "license": "xxxxxxxx",
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        "nsis"
      ],
      "icon": "build/icon.ico",
      "files": [
        "!release-builds/*",
        "!build/*",
        "!.vscode/*",
        "!.gitignore/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "author": "xxxxxxxx",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.9.0",
    "about-window": "^1.13.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "d3": "^5.9.7",
    "d3-context-menu": "^1.1.1",
    "electron-store": "^3.3.0",
    "fast-csv": "^2.5.0",
    "featherlight": "^1.7.13",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fs-jetpack": "^2.2.2",
    "handlebars": "^4.1.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "json-format": "^1.0.1",
    "jsonfile": "^2.4.0",
    "lg-fullscreen": "^1.1.0",
    "lg-pager": "^1.0.2",
    "lg-video": "^1.2.2",
    "lg-zoom": "^1.1.0",
    "lightgallery": "^1.6.12",
    "melanke-watchjs": "^1.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "mousetrap": "^1.6.3",
    "os": "^0.1.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "semver-parser": "^3.0.1",
    "spectrum-colorpicker": "^1.8.0",
    "tabulator-tables": "^4.2.7",
    "upath": "^1.1.2",
    "video.js": "^7.5.5",
    "videojs-offset": "^2.1.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^4.2.6",
    "electron-builder": "^20.44.4",
    "electron-notarize": "^0.1.1",
    "electron-packager": "^13.1.1",
    "electron-reload": "^1.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: You can turn off ```asar``` in package.json then go to your app folder and detect what is large

Comment: @TienDuong - thanks, yeah have done that. Wouldn't the OSX and PC versions include the same resources? Is the Electron runtime that much smaller on PC?

Comment: The resources is difference. It is based on the libraries you used.